# How to approach learning a new library

Tags: lib

As a university student, I already have a programming foundation. When I learn a new library, I typically refer to the developer's documentation to read it, but I struggle to fully understand it and can only follow along. How can I become proficient and easily comprehend library documentation when I am new to it?

I tried to find out and follow.

Comment: I would convert the documentation text to simple English (using generative AI), read through it, and then confirm that the AI didn't make any mistakes by skimming over the key details in the documentation.